# Debian live usb stick with persistence boots without gui on vega gpu systems

Tags: debian, live-usb, gpu, amd-graphics, persistence

background: as corona starts we have made an bootable usb with persistance via rufus and debian-live-10.3.0-amd64-xfce. We installed an vpn client / remmira or freerdp and the users boot it with their private laptops to work from home. But users getting newer notebooks with vega gfx and the old stick boots only without desktop.

So i tried to make a new stick for the new notebooks and installed the vega drivers on debian-live-10.8.0 but it still boots without desktop. Used this for install: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-drivers-on-debian-10-buster

x.org log:

```
[    18.042] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    18.042] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    18.042] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    18.042] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    18.042] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    18.042] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    18.042] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    18.042] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    18.042] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    18.042] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    18.042] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.043]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    18.043]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    18.043] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    18.043] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    18.043] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    18.043] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    18.043] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    18.043] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.043]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    18.043]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    18.043] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[    18.043] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    18.043] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.043] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    18.043] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.043] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    18.043] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    18.043] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[    18.043] (EE) 
[    18.043] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    18.043] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    18.043] (EE) 
[    18.045] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

How can i slove this so the usb-stick works on old/new notebooks with vega gpu?

For example:

```
working gpu "Intel HD Graphics 4000"
not working gpu "AMD Vega Radeon 11 Graphics"
```

Greetings
Rigoletto

Comment: Can you give an example of the graphics difference between old and new laptop (e.g. what hardware is it?)

Comment: added gfx card info